# Sortng mat-table by date doesn't sort rows

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an API which fetches me list of records. I want to display those records sorted by date. i.e The latest record will be on top and like wise.
I have written a typescript code for it but it doesn't seem to order my rows.
Can someone help me what I am doing wrong?

```
 this.recommendationService
        .getJobExecutionStatList(project.id)
        .subscribe(data => {
            // this.jobExecutionList = data;
            let data1:any = data;
            this.jobExecutionList = new MatTableDataSource();
            var sorrtedArray: Array<
                any
            > = data1.sort((n1, n2) => {
                console.log(n1);
                let date1 = new Date(n1.executionDate.replace('T','').replace(/-/g,'/'));
                let date2 = new Date(n2.executionDate.replace('T','').replace(/-/g,'/'));
                if (date1 > date2) {
                    return 1;
                }

                if (date1 < date2) {
                    return -1;
                }

                return 0;
            });
            // this.jobExecutionList = sorrtedArray;
            console.log(sorrtedArray);
            this.jobExecutionList.data = sorrtedArray;
            this.jobExecutionList.sort = this.sort;
            this.jobExecutionList.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this component for creating sorting in the table:

https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview